# What causes ArcPy RuntimeError: TextElementObject: Error in setting text?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I am trying to generate a map book with the following code that I downloaded but I keep getting an errror:

> *File "Y:\Planning\GIS Planning Analyst\projects\county_map_book\9_GenerateMapBook.py", line 18, in
>   <"module>
>       titleText.text = title   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects_base.py", line 77, in
>   _set
>       return setattr(self._arc_object, attr_name, ao) RuntimeError: TextElementObject: Error in setting text*

```
#Read values from input dialog
title = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
organization = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

arcpy.AddMessage("    Updating Title Page ...")
titleMXD = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("path\county_map_book\MapBook_TitlePage.mxd")
titleText = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(titleMXD, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "Title")[0]
titleText.text = title
arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(titleMXD,"path\county_map_book\Output\1_TitlePage.pdf")
del titleMXD
```

Comment: The error might be in grabbing the parameter.  Try replacing the text element using a string you know to be valid, like this: titleText.text = "test string"

Comment: Also, make sure that your Text Element has the name Title.

Comment: To elaborate on @PolyGeo - under the properties of the text element (right-click access), there is an option under the "size and position" tab to give it an "element name"  This should match your code

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that setting empty string to element text will give an error:

```
RuntimeError: TextElementObject: Error in setting text
```

So I used one space instead of empty string and that worked fine.
In your code add this before setting text:

```
if title == '':
  title = ' '
```

Weird behaviour of Python geoprocessing.